# Using a has_many-equivalent in postgresql jsonb fields in rails and nested values

Tags: arrays, simple-form, nested-attributes, ruby-on-rails-4.2, jsonb

I've various models corresponding to network devices based on STI, with only few fields varying between them, that I store in a jsonb field.

Another jsonb field (network_data) stocks an array of network informations in a json format. Here's the content of this field:

```
[{"ip"=>"192.168.1.1","ip_type"=>"1", "services"=>{"ns"=>"0",..., "FIREWALL"=>"1", "DNSresolver"=>"1"},
"network_device_destination_id"=>"9"},{"ip"=>"192.168.1.2","ip_type"=>"0","services"=>{"ns"=>"0","BGP"=>"0",
 ...(other services)},"network_device_destination_id"=>"8"}]
```

The main reason of using STI is the polymorphic assocation between network devices (the key 'network_device_destination_id' in each json record).

I use activerecord stores with the gem for the specific fields directly stored in json and not in a array https://github.com/devmynd/jsonb_accessor
Then, for this storized attributes I can easily use simple form as for a normal attributes.

But for the elements in the array, it's really tricky to process validation, to write forms...

So I was asking myself if it would be possible to make a class for a network record, with its own rules, validations, and accessors, and using a king of nested_attributes array as we would do with a has_many relation.

Something like we would do with this gem:
https://github.com/lailsonbm/awesome_nested_fields

Thank you for your precious advices!

PH

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently trying to do the same (and there will be more of us I think as time passes) and the only real reference I have found is by Seth Faxon on his blog.
[on his blog](http://faxon.org/2015/02/03/edit-rails-activerecord-json-attributes-in-html-forms)

He's doing a variation on has_many by creating a subclass in the parent model, where every row of the json/jsonb is then accessed as an individual associated object Parent::Child.

I'm not sure how well it would go as a substitute for polymorphic association, but I'll give it a go.